# Import Data as Array from TXT File in Java

Tags: java, arrays, notepad

I want to import a data like this from .txt file using Java.
[image: Data in TXT]

I want to import this as an **Array**. The class of data is like this:

```
class SolidStateDrive {
    String brand;
    String model;
    int capacityInGB;
}
```

So if the array from txt file is hardcoded, that would be like this:

```
ssd[0].brand = Samsung;
ssd[1].brand = Adata;

ssd[0].model = Evo970;
ssd[1].model = SU650;

ssd[0].capacityInGB = 512;
ssd[1].capacityInGB 240;
```

The problem is, when i try to read the .txt file, it **only can store 1 data** from first line. If more than one, it will give error **ArrayOutOfBound** Exception.

Im using while loop so that as long as the nextLine is not null, it will loop. This is my code:

```
int n = 0;
    SolidStateDrive[] ssd = new SolidStateDrive[n+1];
    
        try  {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SSD.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
                    ssd[n] = new SolidStateDrive();
                    ssd[n].brand = tmp[0];
                    ssd[n].model = tmp[1];
                    ssd[n].capacityInGB = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
                n++;
            }
            
            br.close();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Update : i already tried this but doesnt work either

```
SolidStateDrive[] ssd = new SolidStateDrive[2];
```

For complete code in that file : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AQ4QRBkt)

Comment: could you please provide your txt file?

Comment: It is fixed now, yes the txt editor in netbeans is just trolling me i think XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in splitting line `String tmp[] = line.split("\t");`.

Take line one from txt `ssd[0].brand = Samsung;` output of split is same as input `ssd[0].brand = Samsung;`.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String tmp[] = line.split("\t");
    ssd[n] = new SolidStateDrive();
    ssd[n].brand = tmp[0];
    ssd[n].model = tmp[1];
    ssd[n].capacityInGB = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
    n++;
}
```

So the `tmp[]` will contain only `tmp[0] = ssd[0].brand = Samsung;`.
When you try to access `tmp[1]` you will get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1.
```

The solution to your problem,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReadData {

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        readData();
    }

    public static void readData() {
        List<SolidStateDrive> ssd = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SSD.txt"))) {
            ssd = br.lines().map(s-> {
                String[] tmp = s.split("\\s+");
                return new SolidStateDrive(tmp[0], tmp[1], Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]));
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        ssd.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}

class SolidStateDrive {
    
    String brand;
    String model;
    int capacityInGB;

    public SolidStateDrive(String brand, String model, int capacityInGB) {
        super();
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.capacityInGB = capacityInGB;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SolidStateDrive [brand=" + brand + ", model=" + model + ", capacityInGB=" + capacityInGB + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me a bit more specific solution? as long as i know that tmp is for determining the string between "\t" or tab. Any solution that i can do so that when it move to a new line, it will assign to new index?

Comment: You messed up in logic. The best way is to read `txt` file as a properties `key/value` and slipt by `=` and try to set the value to `SolidStateDrive()`

Comment: So basically it is not possible like that? Like increment a variable every newLine and then assign it as an index of array?

Comment: You can but it totally depends on how definitive is your txt file.

Comment: Do you have any reference that suit my problem? Any link or keyword would be appreciated. My file is basically like this https://pastebin.com/5xRUN0xJ . It shows up but always with ArrayOutOfBound after that.

Comment: Edited my answer, check the solution. All the best

Comment: Sorry for bothering man, turns out it is the problem of txt editor in netbeans so the tab basically is not tab. After i edit with notepad all the problem is gone XD

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayOutOfBounds exception occurs in the code you posted in pastebin; you have a for loop that loops n+1 times, which will always be 1 more than the number of SSDs in the array.  This is the offending for loop:

```
for (int j=0; j<=n; j++) {
    System.out.println(j+ "\t" +ssd[j].brand+ "\t" +ssd[j].model+ "\t" +ssd[j].capacityInGB);
}
```

To fix it, just change the `<=` to `<`, so the loop goes up to, but not including, `n`, since you started it at 0, not 1.  It should look like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    System.out.println(j + "\t" + ssd[j].brand + "\t" + ssd[j].model + "\t" + ssd[j].capacityInGB);
}
```

Comment: How do i write j<n without including n?

Comment: If you use `j<n`, you will not include n because you are ensuring that j is less than, but not equal to, n.  That is the definition of the `<` operator.

Comment: oh i see, i misunderstand the meaning of without in your sentence. sorry about that.